# How can I correctly choose maximum number of occurrences of a string while grouping by another field?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I am using Postgresql 9.0. I have the following fields in a table: `id, name`.

```
 id    name 
 1     John
 1     Mary
 1     Mary
 1     Mary
 1     John
 1     Mary
 3     Paul
 3     Paul
 3     George
 .     .
 .     .
```

For each `id`, I want to select the name that occurs the most. How can I do that?

I tried with the following query but it doesn't work:

```
select id, max(name) 
from table 
group by id;
```

Comment: `max` will find the name that sorts last lexically, not the name that accurs the most times. You really want a `mode` (in the statistical sense) aggregate for that, and I don't think one is offered. Someone's written one on the wiki, but I doubt it's very efficient. Try it: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode and http://scottrbailey.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/postgres-adding-custom-aggregates-most/

Answer (score 9):

This isn't trivial. First, you want group by id and name and count the rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
...
GROUP BY id, name
```

Then select the maximum count for every id. One way to achieve this is by window functions. The `RANK()` function:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

assigns a number to every row of the result (after the grouping is done), arranging them (the rows) in partitions with the same `id` and ordered by `COUNT(*) DESC`, so for every (partition of) `id`, the row(s) with the maximum count are assigned a rank of 1. Thus we need to put the above in a derived table and use a `WHERE` condition to keep only these rows:

```
WHERE rnk = 1
```

---

The final query is like this:

```
SELECT
    id, name, cnt
FROM
    ( SELECT id, name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnk
      FROM tableX
      GROUP BY id, name
    ) AS tg 
WHERE
    rnk = 1 ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/42a4c/2)**

---

Note that if you have ties in the first place (two or more names with the same maximum count), all these will be returned. If you want strictly one row per id in the final results, you have to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of the `RANK()` and possibly alter the `ORDER BY` clause to explicitly select how the ties will be resolved:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, name ASC) AS rnk
```

Tested: **[SQL-Fiddle test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/51fba/1)**.

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler with some intermediate CTEs?  Or would that badly affect performance?

Comment: @Wildcard CTEs are materialized in Postgres, while derived tables give more options to the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks!  But what do you mean exactly by "derived tables"?  I haven't encountered that term before.

Comment: Derived table is a named/aliased subquery that appears in a `FROM` clause. What is inside the parentheses in my code (named `tg`)